# How to measure average sales using working days?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm using Power Bi desktop to create a sales dashboard, and ran into a small code issue.

---

I need to calculate average sales in a period of working days, and tried:

```
TOTALYTD([Sales];
         dimCalendar[Date];
         dimCalendar[WorkingDays]<=16)
```

`16` is the related working day for `22APR2019` in Brazil.

---

After that I plan to divide it by a month count or another similar method.

The hard coded 16 works very well, however when I try to use another formula instead:

```
TOTALYTD([Sales];
         dimCalendar[Date];
         dimCalendar[WorkingDays]=CALCULATE(MAX(dimCalendar[WorkingDays]);
         LASTDATE(dimCalendar[Date])
         ))
```

It gives an error that I can't use calculate in a `true/false` expression.
I tried to use calculated column, but doesn't work as well.

---

Do you have any idea of how I can create this measure?

Comment: Please edit for formatting, but shouldn't your for example be formatted like:`TOTALYTD([Sales];dimCalendar[Date];dimCalendar[WorkingDays]<=CALCULATE(MAX(dimCalendar[WorkingDays]));LASTDATE(dimCalendar[Date]))` There is what looks like a misplaced right parenthesis.